# Why is this error coming Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a following query

```
select wbod.subject, wbi.object, 
       age(dod.object,wbod.object) as ageOfPerson 
from wasbornin as wbi, 
     wasbornondate as wbod, 
     diedondate as dod 
where wbi.subject=wbod.subject 
  and wbod.subject=dod.subject  
  and age(dod.object,wbod.object) = (select max(age(dod1.object,wbod1.object)) 
                                     from wasbornin as wbi1, 
                                     wasbornondate as wbod1, 
                                     diedondate as dod1 
                                     where wbi1.subject = wbod1.subject 
                                     and wbod1.subject=dod1.subject 
                                     group by wbi1.object)   
group by wbi.object 
ORDER BY wbi.subject;
```

But it is giving following error

```
column "wbod.subject" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select wbod.subject, wbi.object
```

Why is this error coming

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You might want to read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: you are ordering by the wbi.subject therefore need to group

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are selecting this column. And if given group (GROUP BY wbi.object) there are 150 different subjects, which one of them should be returned?

I initially misread the query - order is using wbi.subject, but error is about wbod.subject.

Comment: Why does the `order by` cause this? There are non-aggregated columns in the select list, which are not part of the `group by`.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, would need to see \d of all tables. It's also possible that it's just first field that it reports, and if you'd fix it, another error would show.

Comment: I misread original query - order by is not using the column from error - similar name, another table. This actually gives more credibility to idea above, that it's just first error reported.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your query correctly, you actually don't need the sub-query or the group by:

```
select subject,
       object,
       ageOfPerson
from (
    select wbod.subject, 
           wbi.object, 
           age(dod.object, wbod.object) as ageOfPerson,
           dense_rank() over (partition by dod.subject order by age(dod.object, wbod.object) desc) as rnk
    from wasbornin as wbi
      join wasbornondate as wbod on wbi.subject=wbod.subject 
      join diedondate as dod on wbod.subject=dod.subject  
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Query to be formed is this - "For each place of birth, find the person who is currently dead, and who lived longest. List the name of the person, the place of birth and the age when he died. Order alphabetically by the name of the person."

Comment: @neel: there is no "name of person" in your tables. Only subjects. And the `object` column seems to be a `date` column which makes your tables even harder to understand unless `age` is not the built-in age function but one that you wrote yourself.

Comment: subject is name of person in wasbornondate,diedondate,livesin,wasbornin tables and object is date in wasbornondate and diedondate, and object is placename in livesin and wasbornin